# Django restframework : Filtering against query parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have question about filtering against query parameters.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class MovieTheater(models.Model):
    movietheater = models.ManyToManyField(Movie,null=True,blank=True,through="MovieShowtime")
    movie_theater = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     #east west north south

class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey( MovieTheater, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'theater' )
    movie = models.ForeignKey( Movie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'movie' )
    time = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**serialize.py**

```
class MovieShowtimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movietitle = serializers.CharField(source='movie.title')  
    theatertitle = serializers.CharField(source='theater.movie_theater')  
    area = serializers.CharField(source='theater.city') 

    class Meta:
        model = MovieShowtime
        fields = ( 'movietitle', 'theatertitle','time','area')

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movielink = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='movie-detail')
    showtime = MovieShowtimeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='movie')

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('movielink' ,'title','showtime'  )
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^movies/$', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie-list'),
    url(r'^movies/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie-detail'),)
```

I want to design a url like     `http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/88?city=XXX`

and it will match the result when area equals 'north' ,'east','south','west'

I have to connect two models like:

```
queryset = Movie.objects.filter(pk=88)
queryset2 = queryset.movietheater_set.filter(city='north')
```

But I don't know how to do this in my views.py

Please teach me - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [FilterSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#djangofilterbackend).  In your case it is probably enough to add it to the view:

```
class MovieList(MovieMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    filter_fields = ('showtime__theater__area',)
```

Your models also need some work.  Related names are what allows you access from the foreign key.  Currently you get Movie.movie, when you probably want Movie.showtime

```
class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey( MovieTheater, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'theater' )
    movie = models.ForeignKey( Movie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'showtime' )
    time = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

The serialization needs a little tweak:

```
class MovieShowtimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movietitle = serializers.CharField(source='movie.title')  
    theatertitle = serializers.CharField(source='theater.movie_theater')  

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movielink = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='movie-detail')
    showtime = MovieShowtimeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='movie')
```

You can make a custom filter to shorten the filter_fields url parameter.

Comment: This would make urls like: /movies/?area=XXX

Comment: But the ````area```` is amanytomanyfield in MovieTheater,not in Movie

Comment: The filters work against the serializer, not the model.  Your Serializer describes a source for the field.  I didn't check if that relationship is proper.

Comment: sorry,my mistake.I type wrong.it's ````city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)````

Comment: sorry,I still can't get it.Could you explain what the ````"__"````meaning in ````showtime__theater__area````

Comment: Database lookup.  Works exactly like in ORM chains (like in Model.objects.filter(field__foreignfield=somevalue)